# MongoDB Text Index Error: language override not supported

Tags: mongodb

I am using version 2.6.1. I am trying to create a text index and I'm getting error:

```
{
    "connectionId" : 4932,
    "err" : "language override unsupported: en-US",
    "code" : 17262,
    "n" : 0,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The documents being searched have a "language" field that has a value of "en-US", but it is not used to override the language in a text search. I tried to create the text index to specify a field that doesn't exist ("lang"); however, I get the same error.
I was able to create the index just fine on version 2.6.0. Is there a way to create the text index and ignore the language_override field?

Here is the working command I used on 2.6.0 (doesn't work on 2.6.1):

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ title: "text" }, { name: "TextIndex" })
```

Here is the command I tried on 2.6.1 to specify another language_override field that does not exist:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({ title: "text" }, { name: "TextIndex" }, { language_override: "lang" })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this index already exists (from 2.6.0) or did you drop it before trying to recreate it?   Could you show result of db.collection.getIndexes() and your exact command and its output?

Comment: On GG someone also pointed out the docs link for legal language values: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages

Comment: The index was successfully created in our DEV server 2.6.0.

Comment: When we upgraded out QA server, 2.6.1 is now the latest stable version. We can't create the index on 2.6.1.
getIndexes() results in:
{
    "0" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "MetadataRepository.LibraryMetadata",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    "1" : {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "MetadataId" : 1,
            "IsDeleted" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "MetadataRepository.LibraryMetadata",
        "name" : "MetadataId_1_IsDeleted_1",
        "background" : true
    }
}

Comment: It seems when we create the index it is looking at the "language" field of the documents. We need it to ignore the "language" field and always use the default language of "english".

Answer (score 21):

### Solution:

Set the `default_language` and `language_override` to the same literal value (in your case "en").

### How I got here...

I hit the same problem, also on Mongo 2.6.1.

In my case I created the index with a `language_override` pointing to a language field where there were already documents with unsupported values (e.g. 'ar' - Arabic).

Here's how I was creating the index:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({ 
  "displayName": "text", 
  "about": "text", 
  "email": "text" 
}, { 
  "name": "users_full_text", 
  "default_language": "en",
  "language_override": "language"
});
```

I was hoping it would fall back to the `default_language` when the `language_override` value is unsupported, but apparently not. Here's what Mongo says:

```
{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
  "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
  "ok" : 0,
  "errmsg" : "language override unsupported: ar",
  "code" : 17262
}
```

OK, fine, so the index wasn't created but I should be able to create it without the language_override, right? Wrong - mongo gives me the same error *even though I no longer have the language_override specified*.

The failed attempt at creating the index seems to have left behind some broken version of the index that does not show up anywhere so I can't drop it (it doesn't appear in `db.users.getIndexes()` and dropping it by name doesn't work).

In the end I managed to fix the index by setting the `language_override` to the literal value 'en', like this:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({ 
  "displayName": "text", 
  "about": "text", 
  "email": "text" 
}, { 
  "name": "users_full_text", 
  "default_language": "en",
  "language_override": "en" 
});
```

... to which Mongo replies:

```
{
  "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
  "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
  "numIndexesAfter" : 4,
  "ok" : 1
}
```

Hurrah.

Comment: Just in case you were not aware, the field `language_override` doesn't set a language, it sets a field to look at in the documents of the collection, so if you set a field `en` in your document MongoDB will attempt to use it's value as a language.

Comment: Right, the fix was to set language_override to any value that wasn't a field in my document (I just happened to use "en"). Once I'd managed to replace the broken index by doing _that_ I was able to replace it with one that has no language_override at all.

Answer (score 5):

The value "en-US" is illegal as a language for text indexing according to doc page http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages

MongoDB accepts only a 2 letter code or full name of language.

Hope it helps :)