# PyMongo - "language override unsupported: C++" when creating index

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have the collection `posts` that contains posts that look something like this

```
{
    "_id": "5ae37fd270f3e72399988198",
    "moderator": {
        "flagged": false,
        "reviewed": true,
        "pending": false,
        "time": "2018-04-27 20:34:38.099000",
        "account": "samhamou"
    },
    "author": "cryptohazard",
    "permlink": "security-enhancements-for-steem-messenger",
    "title": "Security enhancements for Steem Messenger",
    "repository": {
        "owner": {
            "login": "kingswisdom"
        },
        "fork": false,
        "html_url": "https:\/\/github.com\/kingswisdom\/SteemMessenger",
        "full_name": "kingswisdom\/SteemMessenger",
        "name": "SteemMessenger",
        "id": 127418766
    }
}
```

I am trying to create an index on the collection in one of my Python files with the following code

```
posts = DB.posts
posts.drop_indexes()
posts.create_index([
    ("author", "text"),
    ("moderator.account", "text"),
    ("repository.full_name", "text")
])
```

but this is giving me the following error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: language override unsupported: C++
```

How can I prevent this from happening? I can create the indexes using code found in the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815024/mongodb-text-index-error-language-override-not-supported):

```
> db.posts.createIndex({
    "moderator.account": "text",
    author: "text",
    "repository.full_name": "text"
}, {
    "language_override": "en"
});
```

However I want to be able to do it from within my Python script instead of having to do it from the MongoDB shell. I tried finding a way to add the `"language_override": "en"` option from within my Python script, but this doesn't seem possible when checking the [documentation for create_index](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index).

Comment: Do you actually want the option? You are not attempting to set in the code you posted, and that would seem fine. Which MongoDB "server" version are you connecting to? As said, the python code works fine but you might have a server that does not support it.

Comment: If you "do" actually want to override the default language ( which I don't think you really do because it's already the default ) then `posts.create_index([("author","text"),("moderator.account","text"),("repository.full_name","text")], language_override="en")`

Comment: @NeilLunn no, but I get an error otherwise. I'm not sure what is causing it.